# Ordering by index in pyhton

Tags: python, algorithm

I have 3 `list` like

```
A = [3,8,10,25] B = [14,15,30,23] C = [24,27,31,34]
```

I need to combine these 3 lists, then sort them and create 3 lists
again with their indexes in python

```
A = [1,2,3,8] B = [4,5,9,6] C = [7,10,11,12]
```

Comment: what are your efforts? where you are facing challenges, what is the desired output?

Comment: @sahasrara62 The desired output is three sorted lists `A = [1,2,3,8] B = [4,5,9,6] C = [7,10,11,12]` as you can see from the post.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the different lists relate to each other? For example, you have `C=[24,27,31,34]` but I don't see it anywhere in your desired output.

Comment: when i combine and sort these lists,  in this output which i desire `C = [7,10,11,12] `  7 is index of 24  `C = [24,27,31,34] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confusing question. However, I think I have found an answer. What you need to do is first create a second, sorted list that combines A, B and C. Then, you need to check where every item in the list goes in the combined list, if that makes sense.

Try this:

```py
A = [3,8,10,25]
B = [14,15,30,23]
C = [24,27,31,34]

combined = sorted(A + B + C)
print(combined)

a = []
b = []
c = []

def order(origin_lst, new_lst):
    for i in origin_lst:
        new_lst.append(combined.index(i) + 1)
    return new_lst

a = order(A, a)
b = order(B, b)
c = order(C, c)

print(a, b, c)
```

You get an output of: `[1, 2, 3, 8] [4, 5, 10, 6] [7, 9, 11, 12]` which looks right to me.

Comment: It's fine I hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Merge the lists into a flat one, reordering, get the index and regrouping with a slice.

```
A = [3,8,10,25]
B = [14,15,30,23]
C = [24,27,31,34]

flat = sum((A, B, C), [])
ordered = sorted(flat)
indeces = [ordered.index(i)+1 for i in flat]
A, B, C = [indeces[len(A)*i: len(A)*(i+1)] for i in range(len(flat)//len(A))]
```

Remark: `list.index`-based methods are not reliable if the there are repeated values among the lists since it returns the first occurrence.